# Can alcohol be requested at any time on an Ethiopian Airlines flight?

Tags: alcohol, ethiopian-airlines

I'm travelling to LAX from Dublin and I would like to just a nice buzz that puts me to sleep. I do know that with unruly passengers, the cabin crews of many airlines are wary of offering too much alcohol but is there a law that prevents a certain amount from being handed out?

I don't have a fear of being unruly on the aircraft as I'm actually quite relaxed and calm when drunk.

Comment: No laws but there are trade association guidelines, see http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b09202lw

Answer (score 4):

Ethiopean Airlines does not specifically [state](https://www.ethiopianairlines.com/AA/EN/services/onboard/economy-class) specific drink limits for passengers, but most airlines will allow flight attendants to refuse to serve you if they subjectively feel you have had too much to drink. They may also have unstated limits. If you are not behaving inappropriately, you will probably be fine.